# How to filter the following dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I would like to filter one data frame I want all the values with '0' at the first column, the problem is that mi csv file has not header I tried

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('big-cluster.csv',delimiter=',',encoding='ISO-8859-15')
print(df.iloc[:,0].isin([0]))
```

However I got:

```
0       False
1       False
2       False
3       False
4       False
5       False
6       False
7       False
8       False
9       False
10      False
11      False
12      False
13      False
14      False
15      False
16      False
17      False
18      False
19      False
20      False
21      False
22      False
23      False
```

my csv file has the following structure:

```
10,hello this is a test
4,just testing code
3,this is fun
4,you are good
10,this is very good
```

the output that I would like to get would be the following:

```
10,hello this is a test
10,this is very good
```

After feedback from here I tried:

```
mask = df[0].astype(str).str.contains("0")
print(df[mask])
```

however I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2392             try:
-> 2393                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2394             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5239)()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5085)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20405)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20359)()

KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-fe5bdde1bff6> in <module>()
     65 '''
     66 
---> 67 mask = df[0].astype(str).str.contains("0")
     68 print(df[mask])
     69 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2060             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2061         else:
-> 2062             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2063 
   2064     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2067         # get column
   2068         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2069             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2070 
   2071         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1532         res = cache.get(item)
   1533         if res is None:
-> 1534             values = self._data.get(item)
   1535             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1536             cache[item] = res

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3588 
   3589             if not isnull(item):
-> 3590                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3591             else:
   3592                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2393                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2394             except KeyError:
-> 2395                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2396 
   2397         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5239)()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5085)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20405)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20359)()

KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that your first field is getting typed as int and not a string.  So, let's use 'astype' and `.str.contains` to check for zeroes.

Let's try:

```
mask = df[0].astype(str).str.contains("0")
print(df[mask])
```

Output:

```
    0                     1
0  10  hello this is a test
4  10     this is very good
```

Comment: @piRSquared thanks that looks good but I got an error, let me update the question,

Comment: @neo33 What is the column name of your first column.  I uses zero because I didn't have your file.  Subsitute 'your column name here" instead of 0.

Comment: When you don't know, you can use `df.iloc[:, 0]`

Comment: @piRSquared thanks I got the result, I really appreciate the support

Comment: @piRSquared  12.5 points to you for the assist. :)  Thank you.